# Ubuntu 17.10 usb ports not working after wake up

Tags: usb, suspend

My problem is as follow: every time i wake up my laptop from suspend the usb ports stop working (2 usb-2.0 and 1 usb-3.0) and i have to reboot to get them working again.

My laptop is an acer aspire e1-410g

Hope you can help me with this.

Thanks!!